# nmcli insufficient privileges during initial VM setup

Tags: networkmanager

I'm auto-provisioning VMs (Debian Buster OS)
During provisioning right after the system is installed the automation tool kicks-in. Among other actions it does (in that order):

- install `NetworkManager`
- add user X, add user to `sudo` group
- import the connection for the user X using `nmcli`

The last step fails with: `Error: Failed to add 'REDACTED' connection: Insufficient privileges.`
However when I log in to the VM (as a root or user X) and add the connection manually - it works (the user X belongs to the `sudo` groups required by polkit used by NetworkManager)

The only relevant log I was able to find:

```
> journalctl -xe -u NetworkManager
...
audit: op="connection-add" ... result="fail" reason="Insufficient privileges"
```

No logs for `polkit` or `dbus`

I've added to the automation tool some logging, namely to dump the `nmcli general permissions` before importing connection:

```
PERMISSION                                                        VALUE 
org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.enable-disable-network             no    
org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.enable-disable-wifi                no    
org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.enable-disable-wwan                no    
org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.enable-disable-wimax               no    
org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.sleep-wake                         no    
org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.network-control                    auth  
org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.wifi.share.protected               no    
org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.wifi.share.open                    no    
org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.settings.modify.system             no    
org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.settings.modify.own                auth  
org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.settings.modify.hostname           auth  
org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.settings.modify.global-dns         auth  
org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.reload                             auth  
org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.checkpoint-rollback                auth  
org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.enable-disable-statistics          no    
org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.enable-disable-connectivity-check  no
```

which clearly indicates that the user cannot perform any action.
However when I login:

```
PERMISSION                                                        VALUE            
org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.enable-disable-network             yes              
org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.enable-disable-wifi                yes              
org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.enable-disable-wwan                yes              
org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.enable-disable-wimax               yes              
org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.sleep-wake                         no              
org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.network-control                    yes              
org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.wifi.share.protected               yes              
org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.wifi.share.open                    yes              
org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.settings.modify.system             yes              
org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.settings.modify.own                yes              
org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.settings.modify.hostname           auth 
org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.settings.modify.global-dns         auth 
org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.reload                             auth 
org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.checkpoint-rollback                auth 
org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.enable-disable-statistics          yes              
org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.enable-disable-connectivity-check  yes
```

I've tried to replicate this on VM with manual:
`apt update && apt install -y network-manager network-manager-openvpn && useradd userx && usermod -a -G sudo userx && su - userx -c "nmcli connection import type openvpn file ...."` without any luck. It just works...

The tool I'm using for setup automation: `salt` (SaltStack)
User is added via [user.present](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/states/all/salt.states.user.html) state.
**I doubt this is Salt's issue**

Can anyone help me to pinpoint what actually is the issue here?

Answer (score 3):

When logged in remotely (via ssh), policykit can treat the requesting process differently.

The default configuration for NetworkManager's PolicyKit permissions is set that way, because when you are sitting in front of the machine, you likely could also tamper with the cable. So, there is more trust in a non-root local user, than in a non-root remote user.

(BTW, the root user always gets a free pass, without even asking PolicyKit).

Basically, use a user that has permissions and/or configure PolicyKit accordingly.

See https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Polkit . See the `<allow_inactive>` permissions. I am not familiar how best to configure PolicyKit. On some distros you'd write a JavaScript snippet, on Debian something else...